# Bulma: How can I define the stack order on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-frameworks, bulma

I am taking the [Bulma flexbox css framework](http://bulma.io/) for a spin - so far its pretty neat! The only stumbling block I've found is that I can't seem to set the display order for mobile devices.

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column foo">Foo</div>
    <div class="column bar">Bar</div>  // Would like this to be first on small deviecs
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Here is what my css looks like:

```
body, html {
    background-color: blue;
}

.foo { order: 2; }
.bar { order: 1; }


@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    body, html {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .foo { order: 1; }
    .bar { order: 2; }
}
```

Comment: You've tried giving that element `order: -1`?

Comment: Thank you Michael! Just gave that a try - no luck. It seems like it's the smallest size/breakpoint that I haven't figured out. I can shift the order in all of the other sizes. I've updated my question to clarify.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. If you can post a live demo (e.g., jsfiddle.net or codepen.io) that may help.

Answer (score 6):

For this answer, I'm assuming you want BAR to display first ONLY on mobile screens. And for larger display screens you want `FOO` to be displayed to the left-most side.

One way to do this is to take advantage of `flexbox` which is what bulma is built off of. On larger screens, bulma gives columns the property `display:flex` which can be used to display contents in rows and columns.

However on smaller screens the display property switches to `block`.  In most cases, when consecutive items have `display:block`, they're going to stack in order.

We can make use of this using a funky workaround. Place `BAR` first in your html. Then add a class to `columns` and style it like so:
HTML:

```
<div class="columns reverse-row-order">
  <div class="column bar">Bar</div>
  <div class="column foo">Foo</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.reverse-row-order{
 flex-direction:row-reverse;
}
```

And here is a `jsFiddle` if you want to see it working: https://jsfiddle.net/99ydhod8/

Answer (score 1):

Assume Your HTMl is like :

```
<div class="columns reverseMe">
<div class="column">First Content</div>
<div class="column">Second Content</div>
</div>
```

If you want to reverse the order using media query , you can do something like this:

```
.reverseMe{
    @include until($tablet) {
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an adequate when using Bulma with SASS, +1
Only thing to note is that bulma likes the convention is-X, so maybe `is-mobile-reversed`?

Answer (score 1):

## Since Bulma 0.9.1

### `is-flex-direction-row-reverse` class

```html
<div class="columns is-flex-direction-row-reverse">
    <div class="column foo">Foo</div>
    <div class="column bar">Bar</div>
</div>
```

*[Source](https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/flexbox-helpers/#flex-direction)*