# Bulma: Change stack order of columns

Tags: css, bulma

How can I change the stack order of columns on mobile or tablet?

For example, the code below shows elements horizontally on wide screens, but when it's shrinked I want `2` to be on top. I don't want to change the html structure to do it.

The example is below:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.3.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column box">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="column box">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41540439/2341603)?

Comment: Thanks for the link but,I don't want to change a html structure to do it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> As of the current [bulma](http://bulma.io/) version `v0.3.1`, there is no feature
>   for the changing the order of columns.

However, you can define custom styles to change the order for mobile, tablet or whatever resolution that you want.

You can define a custom class `.reverse-columns` for example and add it on parent with following styles:

```
@media(max-width: 767px) { /* <== You can change this break point as per your  needs */
  .reverse-columns {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.3.1/css/bulma.css");

@media(max-width: 767px) {
  .custom-columns {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="columns custom-columns">
  <div class="column box">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="column box">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's also a handy variable if using Sass you can access called `$tablet` for breakpoint widths.  This variable and other ones for responsiveness can be found in `initial-variables.sass`.

Comment: This is the right idea, but when I used "column-reverse" it didn't work. I found "row-reverse" works instead. Learned this here: https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/475

Comment: very nice answer

Answer (score 1):

```
@media(max-width: $desktop) {
  .columns.is-reversed-touch {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    display: flex;
  }
}

@media(max-width: $tablet) {
  .columns.is-reversed-mobile {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

You can always add more rules for widescreen etc., but this is what you usually need.

`flex-direction: row-reverse;` is what I would use for `.columns.is-mobile.is-reversed-mobile`. So you can add that rule too.